# how to unhide a div if data is present in JSTL variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I have a simple javascript file that I use to hide some div's on the page load and do some other minor tasks.  What I would like to do is to show one of these div's if there is data in a JSTL variable.  I'm not sure how to go about the logic in that.

I thought a simple

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(jobRunList) gt 0}">
  <script>
       $("#displayData").show();
   </script>
</c:if>
```

would work, but it appears that it is not.  Is there another {better} way to do this?  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your JSTL variable is determined at server-time and doesn't change with the client, could you simply move the code that renders the div inside of that if logic?  That way the div simply won't exist and doesn't need to be shown?  Or do you require that it be there either way?

Comment: Thanks Matt, I swore I tried this before and it didn't work, but... it works now, Thanks again!